# How can I make my while loop less stressful on the browser?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on the "Smallest Common Multiple" challenge on freeCodeCamp.org and have come up with a function that works when the numbers are less than 5 apart from one another but throws `potential infinite loop` warning when they're farther apart.  When I add `// noprotect` to the top of my while loop the browser crashes as warned so I need to figure out what I could be doing differently that puts less stress on the browser.

I broke everything down into smaller functions as I normally would with using angular to try to minimize the main function possibly making it clearer to me but I just don't know where to go from here.

Here's how everything flows.

```
//for organizing the order of numbers to be smallest to largest.
function sortNums(nA, nB){ if(nA < nB){ return true; } else{ return false; } }

//for determining the numbers between numbers provided by user.
function midNums(nA, nB){
  var numList = [];
  for(var i = nA; i <= nB; i++){ numList.push(i); }
  return numList;
}

//checks to see if common multiple is evenly divisible by all numbers between numbers provided.
function midMatcher(num, arr){
  var test = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var numDiv = num % arr[i];

    if(numDiv !== 0){ test.push("f"); }
  }

  if(test.length === 0){ return num; }
  else{ return -1; }
}

//the main function
function smallestCommons(arr) {
    var numOrder = sortNums(arr[0], arr[1]),
        numA = 0, numB = 0, numsM = [],
        numAcur = 0, numBcur = 0,
        numAfact = [], numBfact = [],
        bingo = 0;

    if(numOrder){ numA = arr[0]; numB = arr[1]; }
    else{ numA = arr[1]; numB = arr[0]; }

    numsM = midNums(numA+1, numB-1);

    while(bingo === 0){

      if(numAcur === 0 && numBcur === 0){ numAcur = numA; numBcur = numB; }
      else{ numAcur += numA; numBcur += numB; }

      numAfact.push(numAcur); numBfact.push(numBcur);

      var comCheck = numBfact.indexOf(numAcur);

      if(comCheck !== -1 && numAcur !== numA && numAcur !== numB){
        var midSearch = midMatcher(numAcur, numsM);

        if(midSearch !== -1){ bingo = midSearch; }
      }
    }
  return bingo;
}
```

Originally when checking for matching values I ran a `for` loop on `numAfact`which I eventually realized iterated through all the same data over and over so I refactored it to check against `numAcur` so it would just do it as it iterates, but that still wasn't enough.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you understand why it's saying "potential infinite loop"?

Comment: no.  it says at line 35, which is where I set `numAcur, numBcur`. It doesn't give an error when passing `1,5` into the function, but `1,13` crashes it. so I'm lost lol.

Comment: You initially set `bingo` to 0. Then your `while` loop operates while `bingo` is 0. But you only change the value of `bingo` if you manage to get into the two `if` statements inside that loop. If your variables aren't correct in those `if` statements, then `bingo` is never changed and you'll just be stuck in that while loop.

Comment: You should use better names for your variables, readability will be enhanced significantly. E.g instead of `numAcur`, use `numACurrent`, instead of `numDiv`, use `isNumDivisible`, etc.

Comment: yeah, sometimes I'll get more caught up in trying to think of a name for a variable than coding lol. But how could they wind up being incorrect so long as the logic works properly?

Comment: @Optiq I think the second part of your comment is directed at the other guy. Anyways, naming is a very important part of programming, and I am not kidding. Let me quote Robert Martin: `It is easy to say that names should reveal intent. What we want to impress upon you is that we are serious about this. Choosing good names takes time but saves more than it takes. So take care with your names and change them when you find better ones. Everyone who reads your code (including you) will be happier if you do`.

Comment: I still remember the days when I named my variables `theShit`, `holyCrap`, and etc, and now when I revisit that code, to understand it, I have to spend ten times the amount I would have to spend if only I had chosen good names back then.

Comment: Anyways, how is your function supposed to work ? 30 is the LCM of 10 and 15 and your function has no way of returning true for 30 because you then check if 30 is divisible by all numbers between and including 11-14 ?

Comment: yes. when the function finds a common multiple, it needs to check and see if it's evenly divisible by all numbers in between.  for example, if `numA = 1` and `numB = 13` the function needs to find a common multiple between the two that is evenly divisible by `2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12` which is 360,360.

Comment: You can't increment both `numAcur` and `NumBcur` each time through the loop. They're not going to become equal on the same iteration. If you start with `3` and `5`, the second iteration has `6` and `10`, then `9` and `15`. Read the Wikipedia article on [LCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) to find a good algorithm.

Comment: That's why you're getting an infinite loop.

Comment: and that's why I have the variable `comcheck`  in place using ìndexOf()`to check the `numBfact`array.  It works without error on numbers closer than 5 numbers apart but not on larger ones.  I'll read the LCM link to see what I can discover in there that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with this.

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  var lo = Math.min(arr[0], arr[1]),
      hi = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]),
      fullNumList = [];

  for(var i = lo; i <= hi; i++){ fullNumList.push(i); }

  var numA = fullNumList[0];

  for(var j = 1; j < fullNumList.length; j++){
    var numB = fullNumList[j], numC = numA;

    while(numA && numB){
      if(numA > numB){ numA %= numB; } else{ numB %= numA; }
    }
    numA = numC * fullNumList[j] / (numA + numB);
  }

  return numA;
}
```